# JavaScript variable declaration in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm perusing the AngularJS source code and couldn't help but notice the following:

```
_angular          = window.angular,
/** @name angular */
angular           = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),
```

This line makes sense to me:

```
angular           = window.angular || (window.angular = {}),
```

"Use angular if already defined (from a previous inclusion?) in window, or assign window.angular to an empty object and set angular local variable to window.angular."

Some questions:

1. Why would window.angular already be defined (other than the obvious case of someone has already included it), and why would we care?
2. Why assign _angular as well as angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through the commit history on GitHub, this is for `noConflict` mode, the case where you have an old reference to a variable called `angular` you want to preserve.

Here is the [commit that added `_angular` in](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/12ba6cec4fb79521101744e02a7e09f9fbb591c4).

The feature was then removed [in this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9faabd1ba0b1929785bcf166dc0ff60008e7c442) and the `_angular` reference is redundant at this point.

I'll raise an issue on GH or make a pull request shortly. Update - made a PR.

Comment: You're fast, haha = )

Comment: And... merged https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/06d0f1aea6ffa0767aae7c9c99585b7197dcdbd6